UV editing not showing up in render mode
I just finished an UV editing for a book, but when I go to Render Mode, it seems like it hasn't updated.
Why does that happen?
I've been following a tutorial, and used shading.

This is the uv editing mode, where its fits perfectly. But it isn't applied into render mode


I don't know which tutorial you are following, but why do you think it fits perfectly in UV editing mode? Because the image fills the complete UV area? The image always fits the area, actually the UV area always spans from bottom left of an image to the top right exactly. What has to fit are the UVs of the mesh faces. In the top menu of the UV Editor I can see it is in Vertex Select Mode. If the UV would perfectly fit, there should be vertices (i.e. black dots) be visible in each corner. So I guess there must be something wrong in the tutorial or you did not follow it thoroughly enough.

pls provide blend file. thx.

Does this answer your question? Texture in 3D view won't update as I manipulate the UVs in the UV Editor
